# Firebase Cloud Messaging Unable to Get Token on Vue 3

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, vuejs3, service-worker

I am creating an App that will get real time notification with firebase cloud messaging, but it seems does not work for me.
I am following their documentation an put firebase-messaging-sw.js in root of my vue project.

i post the demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-77byfd?file=src/App.vue)

here is my App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { useTheme } from './services/vuestic-ui/themes'
  import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
  import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging"
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: ",
    databaseURL: "m",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "2",
    appId: ""
  }

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = getMessaging(app)
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: 'mykey' }).then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
    // ...
    console.log({currentToken})
  } else {
    // Show permission request UI
    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    // ...
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  // ...
})

</script>
```

if You run the demo it will say `An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker.`
so little documentation about Firebase cloud messaging with vue 3, I don't know how to register the service worker properly,ho to get this Firebase Cloud Messaging works on vue 3?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is unable to access the route `firebase-messaging-sw.js`, that's why you are getting this error.

Just create an empty JavaScript file in your public folder named `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and this error will be gone.